# lwjgl java library is blocked being for security issues

Tags: java, lwjgl

i am a bit new to java. i have downloaded the "lwjgl" library from the official site and installed it step by the steps as shown in the tutorial.

When I tried to open the "basic applet" which was provided, i faced a "security issue", and the applet was blocked by jvm. after a lot of searching over the net I realized this is a common problem happend after some update of java. after reading and trying some solutions i didn't manage to solve this problem. some of the solutions were very complicated or hard to understand.
i didnt find any solution for this in the official site. if someone is familiar with this problem, and can give me some specific step by step solution i will be grateful, i have spent a lot of hours trying to solve this.

if someone recommends another parallel library it's  also fine.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not related to LWJGL in particular, it's a general constraint that applies to all applets that try to load native libraries. I assume that you already read things like http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Deploying_with_the_LWJGL_Applet_Loader_1_-_Basics . Depending on what you actually want to achieve, I have to ask: Do deliberately want to create an *Applet*? For a normal application, you will not have these issues, of course...

Comment: Thank you marco.<BR> I do intend to create an applet, i just wanted to check everything works before i learn this library. So you say there should be no problem if I would develop my own thing... <br> i just didn't understand what made this application not to work ? why is there a problem with loading native libraries, and what do you mean by "normal applivation" ? <br> thanks !!

Comment: Loading a native library may cause security problems (simply said: the program may execute malicious code). A while ago, Oracle increased the security standards/settings for applets, and now many applets do now no longer work. For LWJGL, this should not be sooo much a problem, because it's *signed* (i.e. it is safe to use it) and it should be possible to get it running. You may have to lower the security settings in the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/jcp.html . An applet can be on a wesite, a normal application not. Do a websearch: "applet vs application java"